# My SQL cursor not fetching data

Tags: mysql-workbench

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Set_Val`()
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE id varchar(10);
  DECLARE cur CURSOR for SELECT id FROM HearthStone.Basic_enUS WHERE type !="Hero" and collectible = "True";
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  OPEN cur;
  SET @uid = 0;
  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO id;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    INSERT into HearthStone.Basic_enUS (id) VALUES (@uid);
    SET @uid = @uid + 1;
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cur;
END
```

The code above runs without crashing. How ever no rows are affected, and I receive No Data retrieve error. The line

```
SELECT id FROM HearthStone.Basic_enUS WHERE type !="Hero" and collectible = "True";
```

Does return data. I don't know what is going wrong. I'm new at MySQL scripting. I'm trying to loop thru all the data and fill in the id column. The id column is now null for all rows.I'm using Workbench 6.2 to run the script.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help so i'm not posting an answer, but try surrounding the SELECT clause in parenthesis

Comment: Can you paste the error message

Comment: @Guarav Lad OP said it runs without crashing, so there is no error message, the select just doesnt affect any rows.

Comment: Just found out it was working but it added new rows instead of changing the ones loaded by the cursor so the warning was just letting me know none of the data i loaded was changed. I fixed it.